# Deleting all linked/child items held in the same SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with items that have ID's. The ID's are also used to show child/parent items within the same table, with an undefined number of levels or parent/child. Like a treenode but stored in a database See sample table below.

```
+----+----------------+-------+----------+
| ID |    Category    | Depth | ParentID |
+----+----------------+-------+----------+
|  1 |  2 Wheels      |     1 | NULL     |
|  2 |  Motorised     |     2 | 1        |
|  3 |  Motorbike     |     3 | 2        |
|  4 |  Scooter       |     3 | 2        |
|  5 |  Moped         |     3 | 2        |
|  6 |  Non Motorised |     2 | 1        |
|  7 |  Bicycle       |     3 | 6        |
|  8 |  Scooter       |     3 | 6        |
|  9 |  4 Wheels      |     1 | NULL     |
| 10 | Car            |     2 | 9        |
+----+----------------+-------+----------+
```

Is there a way that I can select (and from there delete/update etc.) all of the items for any given parent?

For example if I want to pull out all 2 Wheeled Motorised Category, is there any way to passing it the ID 2 and it pulling out:

```
 Motorbike
 Scooter
```

and any other categories that get added in the future including any extra depths that get added.

Kind regards

Matt

Comment: Recursive cte perhaps?

Comment: Its some where to look at least. Thanks Jarlh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE that rebuilds the hierarchy in your table starting from the id you need to extract (2 for example):

```
declare @idToStartFrom int = 2
declare @tmp table ([ID] int, Category nvarchar(50), Depth int, ParentID int)
insert into @tmp values
 ( 1, '2 Wheels'     , 1, NULL)
,( 2, 'Motorised'    , 2, 1   )
,( 3, 'Motorbike'    , 3, 2   )
,( 4, 'Scooter'      , 3, 2   )
,( 5, 'Moped'        , 3, 2   )
,( 6, 'Non Motorised', 2, 1   )
,( 7, 'Bicycle'      , 3, 6   )
,( 8, 'Scooter'      , 3, 6   )
,( 9, '4 Wheels'     , 1, NULL)
,(10, 'Car'          , 2, 9   )

;WITH RET ([ID], Category, Depth, ParentID, [level])
AS
(
    --anchor
    SELECT [ID], Category, Depth, ParentID, 0 
    FROM @tmp 
    WHERE [ID] = @idToStartFrom
    UNION ALL
    --children
    SELECT C.[ID], C.Category, C.Depth, C.ParentID, [level] + 1 
    FROM @tmp AS C
    INNER JOIN RET AS F ON C.ParentID = F.ID 
)
select [ID], Category, Depth, ParentID 
from RET 
where [level] > 0
```

Setting  `@idToStartFrom` = 2 you will get all rows that have `ParentID` = 2:

[image]

This will work at every level, so if you want all 2 wheeled vehicles you can set  `@idToStartFrom` = 1:

[image]

while setting `@idToStartFrom` = 9 will return all 4 wheeled vehicles:

[image]

Comment: Hi Andrea. I've had a play round with the code you provided and it works brilliantly.

Comment: @MattBartlett Hi Matt, I'm glad that my answer helped you!

Comment: it certainly made things more accurate when it came to checking certain things on our server. When combined with a new filing structure, it helped highlight an additional 1200 items that were potentially incorrectly filed... which all need checking manually. Is there a good way to argue that ignorance is better than accuracy?